# Grouping of rows in excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pywin32

I am automating certain excel tasks. Right now, I need to append some missing data into a table which uses Outline levels. I have been using pywin32 all along and I have come to the point where I have appended missing data with outline levels.

I can specify the outline levels using this piece of code:

```
xlSheet.Rows(row_number).OutlineLevel=3
```

But the problem is that I can't specify that this row-`PLA(Outline level=3)` should come under this row-`Incoming &Outgoing money(Outline Level=2)`.

Can you guys help me with a solution (using win32)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution `rangeObj.EntireRow.Group`does what is needed (using win32 library).

```
import win32com.client as win32
xlSheet.Cells(i+2,1).Value=temp_sheet.Cells(j+1,3).Value
xlSheet.Rows(i + 2).OutlineLevel = 2
rangeObj.EntireRow.Group
```

Comment: any idea how we can change the existing group of columns? After inserting the new column I want to cover the new column in the group.   Thanks

Comment: This is not a very clear solution for anyone who  is coming in from behind  to read. For example, where does rangeObj gets declared?