# Group Range of Rows in Excel uisng Python Win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com, group

I am attempting to group a range of rows in Excel using the win32com python api for Excel Objects. I can't seem to get it to work. My code is as follows:

```py
    excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Workbooks.Open(r"pathtomyexcel.xlsx")
    excel.Visible = True
    book = excel.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = book.Worksheets("Test")
    sheet.Activate()
    
    # trying to get a range of rows using various methods.

    # Using cell ranges
    sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(6, 1),sheet.Cells(15,1)).Group
    # Using row ranges
    sheet.Range(sheet.Rows(6), sheet.Rows(15)).Rows.Group
    # Using the rows range method
    sheet.Rows("6:15").Group
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020902/grouping-of-rows-in-excel-using-python) post, but the answer is not clear as noted in the comments. It seems like the group method needs a range object, however my tests above just aren't doing anything. No errors are occurring either.

for reference, I am using python 2.7 and Excel 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided code tested on Python 3.11 + Excel 365. It should work well on your env.

```
# Using cell ranges
sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(6, 1),sheet.Cells(15,1)).EntireRow.Rows.Group()

# Using row ranges
sheet.Range(sheet.Rows(1), sheet.Rows(3)).Rows.Group()

# Using the rows range method
sheet.Rows("20:25").Rows.Group()

# Using A1 reference
sheet.Range("A40:A45").EntireRow.Rows.Group()
```

Comment: Although I posted up the solution I used to solve my question, this answer provides multiple solutions to get the range and as @tall_ExcelHome in the comments to my answers, a selection isn't necessary to isolate the rows to group.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around and piecing some clues I have found here on Stack and using the [VBA API reference library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/) I found the solution.

```
import win32com.client

# Set the excel object
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

# Open an excel document
excel.Workbooks.Open(r"pathtomyexcel.xlsx")

# Make the excel document visible
excel.Visible = True

# Set a variavle to grab the active workbook
book = excel.ActiveWorkbook

# Set a variable to the specific work sheet
sheet = book.Worksheets("Test")

# Activate the sheet. Note, you must activate the sheet you are 
# working in, before the Select() method will work
sheet.Activate()

# Select the range of rows you want to group. 
# In this case, I selected a range by cell indices and used the 
# EntireRow method to select the entire rows of the range
# Need to call the Select method using parentheses () while using 
# the win32com python api, whereas the VBA call doesn't require the parentheses.
sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(6, 1), sheet.Cells(15, 1)).EntireRow.Select()

# Need to set the Group() method on the current selection in the 
# excel object, which is the selection made in the previous line
excel.Selection.Group()

# Bonus code to collapse the grouped rows
sheet.Outline.ShowLevels(RowLevels=1)
```

Comment: You dont' have to select the range before grouping. The key is `Rows.Group()`.